# bash brace expansion not working with zero padding or increment

Tags: bash, syntax, brace-expansion

using GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12):

```
$ echo {1..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

$ echo {01..10}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

$ echo {1..10..2}
{1..10..2}
```

I get the same results if I put these into a script and run it as `bash brace_test.csh`

Why aren't zero-padding and explicit-increment working?

Comment: You name your `bash` scripts with a `.csh` suffix? Seems a wee bit odd to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both zero padding and the step size were added in `bash` 4.

Comment: Thanks!  Any idea why mac would ship with such an older version of bash? (I.e. should I be at all worried that upgrading could break something?)

Comment: As long as you install it along side the system shell (I've got `bash` 4.2 installed as `/usr/local/bin/bash`), everything should be fine. I've heard speculation that the choice to continue shipping version 3.2 has to do with changes made to the license under which version 4 is distributed.